# Erro ao conectar instancia mysql com nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker

Levantei com Docker container mysql

```
docker run --name mysql-docker -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -d -p 3306:3306 mysql
```

Porém ao tentar conectar via node

```
node index.js
```

ocorre o seguinte erro

```
    { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:992:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1014:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1186:14)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (DIRETORIO DO PROJETO\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (DIRETORIO DO PROJETO\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (DIRETORIO DO PROJETO\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:118:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (DIRETORIO DO PROJETO\api\index.js:13:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3306,
  fatal: true }
```

arquivo index.js

```
const mysql = require('mysql');    
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3306,
  user: 'root',
  password: 'password',
});
```

Comment: Você liberou a porta 3306 no docker, mas se conectou na 3307? Por quê?

Comment: Eu alterei o arquivo. Vou alterar o post.

Answer (score 1):

Porta que vc vai usar para sua aplicação acessar -> 3307:3306 <- porta que o container abriu internamente, utilize a porta 3307 na conexão da sua aplicação.

```
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 3307,
  user: 'root',
  password: 'password',
});
```

Ou:

```
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'mysql-docker',
  port: 3307,
  user: 'root',
  password: 'password',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o nome de seu container docker como host no caso pelo que entendi voce nomeou seu container com "mysql-docker", caso tenha duvida a respeito do nome execute "docker ps -a" e verifique o nome do container

```
const mysql = require('mysql');    
const connection = mysql.createConnection({

  host: 'mysql-docker',

  port: 3306,

  user: 'root',

  password: 'password',

});
```

Comment: Com o nome do container não funcionar também